# how to run in background

Tags: java

I want my Java program to run in the background.
How would you do it?
Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "in the background"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not to be decided by the Java program, but by the operating system and the enduser. The enduser has just to configure the operating system so that it get executed during startup or as a scheduled task.

You just have to make sure that your program doesn't spawn any UI or so.

Answer (score 2):

I have often used [Tanukisoftware's Java Service Wrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com) for this exact purpose. It allows you to create a Windows Service for any Java application and it can run in the background, start with the OS, etc.

The "Community Edition" does what you need and is completely free to boot.

Answer (score 1):

If it was Linux I would have said just execute the java app as a background job. Something like

> nohup java your_app &

...

Although I have not used this in windows but by googling I found that start /b command does the same thing. Perhaps you could try something like this:

> start /b java your_app

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making a Swing GUI application and setting setVisible(false)?

Answer (score 0):

What's your definition of "running in the background"? By default, a Java app does not have a console. So if you don't create a window in main, it will have no visible UI. I would think that would qualify as a background job.

Answer (score 0):

to run .java in background use

**java FileName &**

to run .jar in background use

**java -jar FileName.jar &**

Please use **&** at the end to run in background